# How to fit ScrollPane into component bounds

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this ScrollPane which I holds many components. I want to use the ScrollPane into many components with different size.
I solved temporary the problem using Rectangle2D

```
Rectangle2D primaryScreenBoundsthree = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
```

But this is not working properly when I insert the ScrollPane with different components. I also tested this:

```
scrollthree.setPrefSize(ScrollPane.USE_PREF_SIZE, ScrollPane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

But again the result is not appropriate:

How I can fir the ScrollPane into the parent components borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
```

This returns you the `bound of the Screen(Monitor)` which you are using.

```
Bounds is the width and height of the Screen !
```

Inorder to use scrollPane to fit into your parent, don't use `scrollthree.setPrefSize`. You *don't have to specify the size of the scrollPane*, it will automatically `fit into Parent`

Infact, **all the javafx panes fit into their respective parents** !